# JSON - how to merge 2 data set using keys using javascript reduce()

Tags: javascript, json

I have 2 sets of JSON data that I need to merge - merge **productsBrands** with **Products**, what is the best way to achieve this using javascript?

**ProductBrands JSON data:**

```
const productBrands = {
  "Brand A": {
    "Brand D": {},
    "Brand E": {}
  },
  "Brand B": {
    "Brand F": {},
    "Brand G": {}
  }
};
```

**Products JSON data:**

```
const products= [
  {
    "Brand A": {
      "BrandName": "Brand A",
      "HasChildBrands": {}
    },
    "Brand B": {
      "BrandName": "Brand B",
      "HasChildBrands": {}
    },
    "Brand C": {
      "BrandName": "Brand C",
    },
    "Brand D": {
      "BrandName": "Brand D",
    },
    "Brand E": {
      "BrandName": "Brand E",
    },
    "Brand F": {
      "BrandName": "Brand F",
    },
    "Brand G": {
      "BrandName": "Brand G",
    }
  }
];
```

**Expected Merged output:**

```
const products= [
  {
    "Brand A": {
      "BrandName": "Brand A",
      "HasChildBrands": {
        "BrandName": "Brand D",
      },
      {
        "BrandName": "Brand E",
      }
    },
    "Brand B": {
      "BrandName": "Brand B",
      "HasChildBrands": {
        "BrandName": "Brand F",
      },
      {
        "BrandName": "Brand G",
      }
    },
    "Brand C": {
      "BrandName": "Brand C",
    },
    "Brand D": {
      "BrandName": "Brand D",
    },
    "Brand E": {
      "BrandName": "Brand E",
    },
    "Brand F": {
      "BrandName": "Brand F",
    },
    "Brand G": {
      "BrandName": "Brand G",
    }
  }
];
```

**Below is what I have tried so far, but its still not what I expected:**

```
let products = data.reduce(function (acc, obj) {
  let item = Object.values(obj)[0]; //Get Indented Objects of Data
  let BrandNames = item.BrandName; //Obtain "Brand A", "Brand B", "Brand C" ... so on.
  let KeysForChildBrands = Object.keys(childBrands);
  if($.inArray(BrandNames, KeysForChildBrands) != -1){ //Check if Brand Name existed in ProductBrands data
    item['HasChildBrands'] = ProductBrands[BrandNames];
  }
  acc.push(obj);
  return acc;
},[]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(products)); //Got stuck here.
```

Comment: What is your way for doing it, and why do you think your way is not the best?

Comment: Its not valid json object.

Comment: why wrapping a single object inside of an array? are there more objects to come?

Comment: I have been trying to merge them but stucked

Comment: @Mike its great that you have been trying. If you "wrap up" your trials into some code and place it inside the question, that could be an awesome starting point for us. It would also help you sort out the problem in your own mind.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. Show what you have tried so people can help you fix **your code**

Comment: I just added my trial code, in which you can see I got stuck appending sibling data a parent set. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change the format for `products` to simplify your computation as now `products` is an array of objects

I know this is not aligned to your output as in the resultant array you have repeating `BrandName` keys which is not a correct syntax and the below is the correct form in which you should maintain data(at least logically it is correct but mught not be efficient)

```
var productBrands = {
  "Brand A": {
    "Brand D": {},
    "Brand E": {}
  },
  "Brand B": {
    "Brand F": {},
    "Brand G": {}
  }
};

var products= [
    {
      "BrandName": "Brand A",
      "HasChildBrands": {}
    },
    {
      "BrandName": "Brand B",
      "HasChildBrands": {}
    },
    {
      "BrandName": "Brand C",
        "HasChildBrands": {}
    },
    {
      "BrandName": "Brand D",
        "HasChildBrands": {}
    },
    {
      "BrandName": "Brand E",
        "HasChildBrands": {}
    }

];

for(obj in products)
{

    products[obj].HasChildBrands = productBrands[products[obj].BrandName];
}
console.log(products);
```

Comment: Wow, it works! I am still got long way to go with data manipulation, I think you are right I should simplify format for the JSON data, good point to learn from. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just convert your `HasChildBrands` to an array

```
"Brand A": {
    "BrandName": "Brand A",
    "HasChildBrands": []
},
```

and data to an object instead of an array

```
const data= {
    "Brand A": {
      "BrandName": "Brand A",
      "HasChildBrands": []
    },
    "Brand B": {
      "BrandName": "Brand B",
      "HasChildBrands": []
    },
    "Brand C": {
      "BrandName": "Brand C",
    },
    "Brand D": {
      "BrandName": "Brand D",
    },
    "Brand E": {
      "BrandName": "Brand E",
    },
    "Brand F": {
      "BrandName": "Brand F",
    },
    "Brand G": {
      "BrandName": "Brand G",
    }
  };
```

Use This piece of code to merge the objects

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(val){
        if(childBrands[val]){
           var childs = Object.keys(childBrands[val]);
           childs.forEach(function(child){
               data[val].HasChildBrands.push({'BrandName':child});
           });

        }
    });
```

**SNIPPET**

```js
const childBrands = {
  "Brand A": {
    "Brand D": {},
    "Brand E": {}
  },
  "Brand B": {
    "Brand F": {},
    "Brand G": {}
  }
};

const data= {
    "Brand A": {
      "BrandName": "Brand A",
      "HasChildBrands": []
    },
    "Brand B": {
      "BrandName": "Brand B",
      "HasChildBrands": []
    },
    "Brand C": {
      "BrandName": "Brand C",
    },
    "Brand D": {
      "BrandName": "Brand D",
    },
    "Brand E": {
      "BrandName": "Brand E",
    },
    "Brand F": {
      "BrandName": "Brand F",
    },
    "Brand G": {
      "BrandName": "Brand G",
    }
  };

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(val){
    if(childBrands[val]){
       var childs = Object.keys(childBrands[val]);
       childs.forEach(function(child){
           data[val].HasChildBrands.push({'BrandName':child});
       });
  
    }
});

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It works, and I think yours is the closest to what I want. Thanks for helping.